# RTL support in Android Widgets

Tags: android

How do I make layouts render with correct [layout-direction-configuration](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL) in Android Widgets? I have a layout that successfully supports RTL and LTR when rendered in an activity, but when put in a widget it is forced LTR. Any secret to this, or does widgets simply not support RTL-configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Set this attibute in parent layout:

```xml
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
```